# PHP - Unable to parse attribute using SimpleXML

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Given the following xml:

```
 <data xmlns:ns2="...">
     <versions>
            <ns2:version type="HW">E</ns2:version>
            <ns2:version type="FW">3160</ns2:version>
            <ns2:version type="SW">3.4.1 (777)</ns2:version>
     </versions>
    ...
 </data>
```

I am trying to parse the third attribute ~ns2:version type="SW" but when running the following code I get nothing..

```
$s = simplexml_load_file('data.xml');

echo $s->versions[2]->{'ns2:version'};
```

Running this gives the following output:

```
$s = simplexml_load_file('data.xml');

var_dump($s->versions);
```

[image]

How can I properly get that attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got some quite annoying XML to work with there, at least as far as SimpleXML is concerned.

Your `version` elements are in the `ns2` namespace, so in order to loop over them, you need to do something like this:

```
$s = simplexml_load_string($xml);

foreach ($s->versions[0]->children('ns2', true)->version as $child) {
  ...
}
```

The `children()` method returns all children of the current tag, but only in the default namespace. If you want to access elements in other namespaces, you can pass the local alias and the second argument `true`.

The more complicated part is that the `type` attributes is **not** considered to be part of this same namespace. This means you can't use the standard `$element['attribute']` form to access it, since your element and attribute are in different namespaces.

Fortunately, SimpleXML's `attributes()` method works in the same way as `children()`, and so to access the attributes in the global namespace, you can pass it an empty string:

```
$element->attributes('')->type
```

In full, this is:

```
$s = simplexml_load_string($xml);

foreach ($s->versions[0]->children('ns2', true)->version as $child) {
  echo (string) $child->attributes()->type, PHP_EOL;
}
```

This will get you the output

```
HW
FW
SW
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the third attribute.

```
$s = simplexml_load_file('data.xml');
$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($s);
foreach ($sxe as $out_ns) { 
    $ns = $out_ns->getNamespaces(true); 
    $child = $out_ns->children($ns['ns2']);  
} 

echo $child[2];
```

Out put:

3.4.1 (777)